# Alternative method to check whether a number is present in a given range or not?

Tags: vb.net, numbers, range

If i want to check a number(`X`) in between certain limit (`55` -`100`) then i need to check with the following condition

```
If x >= 55 and x <= 100 then
    MsgBox("Number is within the given Range")
Else
    MsgBox("Number is not within the given Range")
End If
```

**is their any simplest way to check this?**

like `BETWEEN` in `SQL` as

```
x BETWEEN 55 and 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think their is no such operator is available, You can use `SELECT CASE` instead for this as an alternative.

```
 Dim x As Integer = 72
 Select Case x
    Case 55 To 100
        MsgBox("Number is within the given Range")
     Case Else
        MsgBox("Number is not within the given Range")
 End Select
```

**Or in another way you can use `Enumerable Range`**

```
 Dim x As Integer = 72
 Dim rng = Enumerable.Range(200, 200)
 If rng.Contains(x) Then
    MsgBox("Number is within the given Range")
 Else
    MsgBox("Number is not within the given Range")
 End If
```

Both can't be say as a **simplest method but an alternative method for this**

Answer (score 2):

You want a Select Case Statement:

```
    Select Case x
        Case 55 To 100
            MsgBox("Number is within the given Range")
        Case Else
            MsgBox("Number is not within the given Range")
    End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to create a generic extension method constrained by the [IComparable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. It's implemented by all of the primitive types (++).

```
Public Module Extensions

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function Between(Of T As IComparable(Of T))(value As T, minimum As T, maximum As T) As Boolean
        Return (value.CompareTo(minimum) >= 0) AndAlso (value.CompareTo(maximum) <= 0)
    End Function

End Module
```

Usage:

```
If x.Between(55, 100) Then
Else
End If
```

Comment: By far the best answer going. One can also make use of Function overloading to make additional `Between` extensions better specialized for the data type. For example, one for `Integer`, returning `Return value >= minimum AndAlso value <= maximum`.

Comment: Sure, but I find this more scalable. As is, it supports: `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Char`, `DateTime`, `DateTimeOffset`, `Decimal`, `Double`, `Guid`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `SByte`, `Single`, `String`, `TimeSpan`, `UInt16`, `UInt32`, `UInt64` and `Version`.

Comment: No arguments here regarding scalability and support for all the value types you listed. I guess what I'm wondering about is on whether there is a performance cost in using `CompareTo` versus the operators (`<=` and `>=`). I.e. would use of `CompareTo` interfere with compiler optimizations, such as inlining?

Comment: I should add that your very scalable Between extension can be used alongside any specialized ones.